# floating point constant in C, bit representation

Tags: c, types, floating-point, constants

It is possible to access to the bit representation of a floating point constant in C;

For example i'd like to assign

```
uint64_t x = //bit representation of 5.74;
```

which is represented by
    0x40b7ae14

Do you think it is possible?

Comment: `uint64_t x =  0x40b7ae14;` will work.

Comment: `float x = 5.74; uint32_t y; memcpy(&y, &x, sizeof(y)); ` Note that `float` is usually 32 bits, not 64.

Comment: yeah i know... but my question was if it is possible to say straight "infer the 0x... from 5.74".

Comment: @EOF, i will try, but i thought 5.74f were the "float value" while without "f" it should be the treated as double isn't?

Comment: @Lukkio: Yes, but it is implicitly converted by assigning to a `float`-variable.

Comment: Note that the behaviour will be implementation dependent.

Comment: But i'm understanding that it is impossible to do a straight assignement with the constant value, without using a float or double variable i mean.

Answer (score 5):

One way of achieving this is to use a union:

```
union {
    double fltValue;
    uint64_t uintValue;
} conversion;

conversion.fltValue = 5.74;
printf("%#llx\n", conversion.uintValue);
```

Updated with `%#x` thanks to Aracthor for mentioning it. And `%#llx` thanks to EOF.

For a working example (with `float` instead of `double`) see:

https://ideone.com/p4rH5l

Comment: Your `printf()` is wrong, it needs `"%#"PRIx64"\n"` when printing a 64-bit number.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I looked for this limitation in the C standard (C11), and didn't find it, it may be that I looked at the wrong place, but I thought it had been removed from the standard. I take your word for it though.

Comment: Changed previous comment per EOF's one. Extract from C99 draft 6.2.6.1 :  *When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object
representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members
take unspecified values*. It is not explicitely UB and should not be optimized away for that reason, but C does not specify what values of other members should be.

Comment: Sorry, my C-standard-foo was a bit weak, the relevant part is actually a footnote: Section `6.5.2.3 §3, footnote 95): If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation.`

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but is not portable because you cannot be sure of how a floating point value is represented : C standard does not define it.

You could simply use casting of pointers :

```
float x = 5.74;
void *pt = &x
uint64_t *ip = pt;
uint64_t i = *ip;
```

This is formal undefined behaviour because you are casting a pointer to a different type, and you should not do it because you add endian problems to the floating point representation.

The correct way would be :

```
float x = 5.74;
void *pt = &x
unsigned char *ip = pt;
```

`ip` now point to a `unsigned char[]` of size `sizeof(float)` containing the binary representation of a float. And no undefined behaviour was invoked because casting a pointer to a `void *`or a `char *` is always allowed.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double x = 5.74;
    uint64_t y = *((uint64_t*)&x);
    printf("0x%016llx", y);  /* 0x4016f5c28f5c28f6 */
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon. Please expand on your answer with some explanation of how your code addresses OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for the binary representation of float, then take an integer pointer..assign the address of the float variable to the integer pointer and by derefenencing the value of int pointer, get its binary form..and in the middle if you somehow want to avoid the warning generated by unusual typecasting then you can always use void*